# update xml file using java xpath knowing absolute path

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

for example we have this file xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<config>
  <Connections>
    <DbMetaData tablePrefix="example"/>
    <Date>inOut</Date>
    <AGSConnection
                  outputDirectory="C:\directory2\directories\isoutput"
                  virtualOutputDirectory="https://directory1.example1.net/ex/rest/output"/>
    <SDEConnection
                  server="srv01" 
                  instance="sde:sqlserver:srv01" 
                  database="DBex" 
                  authenticationMode="DBMS"
                  user="user1" 
                  password="pass123" 
                  version="sde.DEFAULT"
                  sdeConnectionPath="C:\\tmp\\ex\\conexion\\ser01.sde"/>
 </Connections>
 </config>
```

if we want to edit the values in nodes "new value" and "server=new value" using xpath, which would be the code?
I wrote the following code but does not work, do not give me error messages, simply generate the new XML file but without changes:

```
            File file = new File(fileXML);
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = dBuilder.parse(file);         
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String expression = "/config/Connections/SDEConnnection/server";
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate(pathNodo,doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);         
            for (int idx = 0; idx < nodes.getLength(); idx++) {
                Node node = nodes.item(idx);
                node.setTextContent(valorNodo);
            }        
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File("C:/test.xml")));
```

what would be the correct expression to edit the value on each node:
"new value"--/config/Connections/Date
"server=new value"--/config/Connections/SDEConnnection/server

thanks,

Comment: I see that was not published correctly my question.

Comment: node--  <Date>new value</Date> --config/Connections/Date

Comment: and node-- <SDEConnection server=new value></SDEConnection>--/config/Connections/SDEConnnection/server

Comment: "server" is not a node but an attribute. Get the Node SDEConnection and modify its attribute from there. Search for SDEConnections with specific Values for server this way: //SDEConnection[@server='srv01'] for example.

Comment: @elfwyn `server` actually is a [_node_](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_nodes.asp) (of type _attribute_). It's not a node of type _element_.

Comment: Sorry then, for my uneducated answer ^_^!. Nontheless: It would be better to integrate the comments made to correct the question into the question itself. It has become quite confusing for me to follow what exactly is needed.

Comment: for such a simple piece of code, the best option is probably vi or emacs. Have you considered those?

Answer (score 0):

I see following problems in your code:

a) You need to get attribute in your xpath expression, you specify `@` like :

`//config/Connections/SDEConnection/@server`

b) You need to pass expression to evaluate, I don't know what is `pathNodo` that you are passing currently. You need to pass expression like:

`NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate( expression,doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);`

or actually I prefer :

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/config/Connections/SDEConnnection/server";

XPathExpression xPathExpr = xPath.compile( expression );
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPathExpr.evaluate( doc, XPathConstants.NODESET );
```